# What do @ and ! mean?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, symbols

```
 suffixes :: [a] -> [[a]]
 suffixes xs@(_:xs') = xs : suffixes xs'
 suffixes _          = []
```

I only know that @ here is called "AsPattern". But how does it actually work here ?
Is there anyone can give me a analysis?

And how does ! work in haskell.
I can not give an example right now. But I am pretty sure it does occur in the haskell programming .

Comment: You can search for symbols on Hoogle https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=!

Answer (score 8):

The @ symbol allows you to pattern match and refer to the entire value you are pattern matching against. In your example you can refer to the whole list argument as xs (using the @ symbol) and the tail of the list as xs' (using pattern matching).

The ! symbol can be used to force a value to be evaluated strictly instead of lazily (using bang patterns or strictness annotations).

Comment: `!` is also used for strictness annotations, which are distinct from bang patterns.

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, you can use an As Pattern to give an argument an alternative name by which you can refer to it. In your case,

```
xs@(_:xs')
```

allows you to use xs as an alternative name for the argument (_:xs').  Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to do this because _ matches any argument, but is unusable otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` symbol is used to bind `xs` to the pattern that you have used (`_:xs')`, so `xs'` is bound to the tail of the list and `xs` is bound to the head consed onto the tail of the list.  The `!` used for O(1) constant time indexing of a vector.  See the documentation here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.9.1/docs/Data-Vector.html

Comment: `!` is also used in other contexts than vector indexing.

Answer (score 2):

**!** can be a keyword in which case [it may be a strictness annotation or bang pattern](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.21).

[**!** can also be a function name](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array.html#v:-33-) defaulting to infix application (aka. an operator) of which there are many library examples including array indexing.

[**@** is a keyword for an as pattern (aka. view pattern)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#.40).  It can also be [part of a function name like it is for several HUnit assertions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.2.5.2/docs/Test-HUnit-Base.html).

[Interesting uses of bang patterns and view patterns](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/pattern-and-guard-extensions) are described at the School of Haskell.